# Is there a isAfter method for temporal in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I know there are `isAfter` method for both `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate`.

However it would make my life much easier if I could mix those classes ie `LocalDate.isAfter(LocalDateTime)` without casting one of the classes to another.

Comment: How can you compare a date with a date/time? Is July the 1st before or after July the 1st 15h00? The date needs to be set a time.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following, however it's not clear whether a LocalDate means the start of that day, or any time in that day.

```
// is midnight of localDate after localDateTime
boolean afterStartof = localDate.atStartOfDay().isAfter(localDateTime)
```

or after any time in the day

```
// is localDate after the day in localDateTime
boolean afterThatDay = localDate.isAfter(localDateTime.toLocalDate());
```

In short the behaviour when the dates match is undefined, you need a way to

```
if (localDate.isEqual(localDateTime.toLocalDate())) {
    // what do we do?
```